# Set a variable with bash that can be read in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, bash, cron

I need to set a variable with a bash script that can be read by apache within a `.htaccess` file. The bash script is frequently called by cron.

When I do

```
var=value
export var
```

and I try to call it in .htaccess with `$var` it wont work. So, what can I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are pretty limited with regards to [Apache httpd environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html)

1. Set the variable in your script and restart your webserver from that script to expose it as an OS environment variable to Apache with `PassEnv`. That is probably a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>.
2. Apache HTTP Server provides a mechanism for storing information in named variables that are also called environment variables. And although these variables are referred to as environment variables, they are not the same as the environment variables controlled by the underlying operating system.
   You probably need to write such variables with `SetEnv` to your `.htaccess` file to be able to use them there...